# For loop in python function not running or displaying anything

Tags: python

I have a relatively simple code defining a function add() which adds a list into a csv file books.csv . This file already contains data and isnt empty . This code has two for loops which should run as it has no condition to them but neither of them show any result . There is another edit() function which has been defined and works perfectly

```
import csv
def add(n,m,o):
    with open('books.csv','a') as f2:
        f3=csv.writer(f2)
        f = open('books.csv', 'r')
        f4=csv.reader(f)
        for i in f4:
            if i==[]:
                continue
            elif i[0]==n:
                print('Book Code already exists')
                add(n,m,o)
        l=[n,m,o]
        f3.writerow(l)
        for i in f4:
            if i==[]:
                continue
            else:
                print('Name:',l[1],'Author:',l[2],'BookID:',l[0])
                y=input('Do you wish to change any information entered before? [Y/N]')
                if y=='y' or y=='Y':
                    edit()
                else:
                    return
```

Comment: May I ask why you are recursively calling `add(n,m,o)`? It seems that if `i[0] == n` for two given files, it will continually call itself with the same parameters.

Comment: This function clearly should not be recursive.  Most of your bugs are probably due to that, for obvious reasons.  Eliminate it.  Problem solved.

Comment: Oh yea thats one thing , but even when i remove it it has the same output again , for loops still dont run

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. We don't know what data you are running on, what `n`, `m` or `o` are...

Comment: ``for i in f4:`` (twice) - you can only iterate the iterator once. as others pointed out, the recursion does not help with analyzing what's going on either. I suggest you read through: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and get familiar with an IDE that supports debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your program should take entries like

```
n = 463782 # the book ID
m = 'Some Book Title' # the title of the book
o = 'Author McAuthorface' # the author's name
```

It then opens a csv file, where there are a lot of books already stored (each with an id, title, author). Your code then looks for the id, and if it is there prints title and author.
(There is no way for us to know what edit() is supposed to do btw...)

A much easier way to do this, would be to use dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('books.csv')
df.columns = ['id', 'title', 'author']
```

You can then access any line directly by calling

```
df[df['id'] == n]
```

This will return all lines, where the condition is true. You are not even limited to searching a specific id, you can do the same with author for example, to get all books from a specific author.

Best thing is, there is no need for a loop - and your code is much, much, much faster.

You can then easily edit any values in the dataframe, and finally write it back into a csv with e.g.

```
df.to_csv('new_book_list.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a row to a CSV is rather simple, even in the case that you want to skip adding it if a row with a given id already exists.

Unfortunately, removing or altering an existing row is much more difficult as it kind of requires that either one reads and overwrites the entire dataset.

```py
def add(book_id, author_name, book_title):
    ##---------------------
    ## make our parameters look like a "book"
    ##---------------------
    book_new = [book_id, author_name, book_title]
    ##---------------------

    ##---------------------
    ## no need to re-enter the path to the csv all the time
    ##---------------------
    books_path = "books.csv"
    ##---------------------

    ##---------------------
    ## read all the book records into a list
    ##---------------------
    with open(books_path, "r") as file_in:
        books = list(csv.reader(file_in))
    ##---------------------

    ##---------------------
    ## Try to find an existing book with the given ID
    ##---------------------
    for book in books:
        if book[0] == book_new[0]:
            print(f"Book { book[0] } already exists.")
            print(f"\tExisting Author: \"{ book[1] }\" New Author: \"{ book_new[1] }\"")
            print(f"\tExisting Title: \"{ book[2] }\" New Title: \"{ book_new[2] }\"")

            if "y" == input("\tMake this update? [Y/N] ").lower():
                book[1:3] = book_new[1:3]

            break
    else: # AKA NO_BREAK (no existing book found)
        books.append(book_new)
    ##---------------------

    ##---------------------
    ## Write out the datafile
    ##---------------------
    with open(books_path, "w", newline="") as file_out:
        csv.writer(file_out).writerows(books)
    ##---------------------
```

Ideally, when we call `add()` and there is no existing record, it would be great if we could just append to the file rather than overwrite is completely. With that in mind, let's make that alteration.

```py
def add(book_id, author_name, book_title):
    ##---------------------
    ## make our parameters look like a "book"
    ##---------------------
    book_new = [book_id, author_name, book_title]
    ##---------------------

    ##---------------------
    ## no need to re-enter the path to the csv all the time
    ##---------------------
    books_path = "books.csv"
    ##---------------------

    ##---------------------
    ## read all the book records into a list
    ##---------------------
    with open(books_path, "r") as file_in:
        books = list(csv.reader(file_in))
    ##---------------------

    ##---------------------
    ## Try to find an existing book with the given ID
    ##---------------------
    for book in books:
        if book[0] == book_new[0]:
            print(f"Book { book[0] } already exists.")
            print(f"\tExisting Author: \"{ book[1] }\" New Author: \"{ book_new[1] }\"")
            print(f"\tExisting Title: \"{ book[2] }\" New Title: \"{ book_new[2] }\"")

            if "y" == input("\tMake this update? [Y/N] ").lower():
                ##---------------------
                ## Overwrite the data with our updated data
                ##---------------------
                book[1:3] = book_new[1:3]
                with open(books_path, "w", newline="") as file_out:
                    csv.writer(file_out).writerows(books)
                ##---------------------

            return
    ##---------------------

    ##---------------------
    ## No existing book was found, so just add it
    ##---------------------
    with open(books_path, "a", newline="") as file_out:
        csv.writer(file_out).writerow(book_new)
    ##---------------------
```